# semisimple Lie algebra and proof of decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

A step I don't understand in the proof of the uniqueness of the decomposition of a simple Lie algebra.

We first proof that $$L = L_1\oplus \cdots\oplus L_n$$ with $L_i$ simple ideals.

Now I take $I$ a simple ideal then $$[I,I]\subset[I,L] = I$$

Why is $[I,L] = I$?

What I would say is that $[I,L]$ is an ideal included in $I$ and is this either $I$ or $\{0\}$ but I don't know how to exclude the second possibility.

Comment: I think that in the last line where you write 'What I would says is that $[I, I]$ is an ideal...' you actually meant to write: 'What I would says is that $[I, L]$ is an ideal...'. I cannot edit it for you since edits need to be at least 6 characters long, but perhaps you can change it yourself?

Comment: Yes you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of simple Lie algebra has two parts:

1) It has no non-trivial ideals

2) It is non-abelian

You use 1) to reduce the possibilities to $\{0\}$ and $I$. You can use 2) to rule out zero.

(A simple ideal is an ideal that is simple when considered as a Lie algebra by itself)

**REMARK:** it is good to realize that every linear subspace of an abelian Lie algebra is an ideal, so you really only need to invoke 2) in the special case that $I$ is 1-dimensional. (Or from the perspective of simple Lie algebras rather than your specific question: the 'additional' axiom 2) in the definition of simple only rules out one (otherwise) simple Lie algebra: the one-dimensional one.)

Answer (score 1):

$[I,L]\subset I$ is an ideal of $I$. This implies that $[I,L]$ is $I$ or $\{0\}$, now $[I,I]\neq 0$ since $I$ is not Abelian, you deduce that $[I,I]=I$.